# How to create an SSIS custom task that references another library

Tags: c#, plugins, ssis

How can one successfully reference a library from an SSIS Task library?  EX: MyCompany.SsisTasks.AwesomeTask have a reference to MyCompany.SsisTasks.Common?  When I try to do this, this is what pops up:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'AwesomeTask,
>   PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system
>   cannot find the file specified.

I have created a new SSIS task doing all of the basic steps (inhert from Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Task, etc).  Doing this worked like a charm, and everything was fine.  The project has expanded and I now am referencing another library with this task.  When I add the task to SSIS now, I get the aforementioned error.  So it would seem I am incorrectly referencing "one of its dependencies."  I am curious if anyone has experience with this.

Comment: Is MyCompany.SsisTasks.Common registered in the GAC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is this: make sure all assemblies are in the GAC, and also make sure that when referencing other assemblies (UITypeString, for instance) to include Class, Assembly, Version, Culture, and PublicKeyToken.